# Display image button from external source

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm working on a project where I need to display image buttons with some images saved in the sd card or from an Url. How can I do this? Or what's best practice?
The objective is to change the image on the button only replacing the file in the sd card.
There are other solutions if I don't know which images will be displayed in future?
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to load an image from a URL into a Drawable object:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL("http://my.url/path/to/image").getContent();
Drawable buttonBg = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
```

Then set it as the background:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonBg);
```

or for API 16+ use:

```
button.setBackground(buttonBg);
```

If you want to read from a file, use a FileInputStream like so:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("/my/path/to/image"); 
Drawable buttonBg= Drawable.createFromStream(fis, null);
```

Comment: Well I'm having some proble...If I surround Input stream url with try/catch (otherwise I get error) get createFromStream variable not initialized... I've tryed to initialized but app crash on lunch...

Answer (score 0):

@carmex
Solved:

```
    ImageButton box1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.box1);
    Drawable drawable = GetImg("path/to/image.jpg"); 
    box1.setBackground(drawable); 


    private Drawable GetImg(String url) 
    { 
     try 
     { 
      InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(); 
      Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name"); 
      return d; 
     }
     catch (Exception e) 
    { 
    System.out.println("Err="+e); return null; 
    } 
    }
```

Thx a lot.